# Preimage of the complement

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For a subset $X$ of $Y$, $f^{-1}(X') = (f^{-1}(X))'$. Here $'$ denotes the complementary set.

Is this true? If so, what would be a proof for it? If it isn't, what would be a counterexample? I'm completely lost.

Comment: Maybe $X'$ is the complementary set of $X$?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You apparently are given a function $f\colon A\to Y$. Let's try.

An element $a\in A$ belongs to $f^{-1}(X')$ if and only if $f(a)\in X'$ or $f(a)\notin X$, which means $a\notin f^{-1}(X)$ or $a\in (f^{-1}(X))'$.

I like to set these chains in a column
$$
a\in f^{-1}(X')\\
f(a)\in X'\\
f(a)\notin X\\
a\notin f^{-1}(X)\\
a\in (f^{-1}(X))'
$$
and then I observe that any line is a consequence of the line above, but also of the line below.

Comment: In summary, $f^{-1}(Y\setminus X)=f^{-1}(Y)\setminus f^{-1}(X)$, right?

Comment: @Filippo Yes, that's correct.