# $K=\{E|f^{-1}(E)\in \mathcal{S} \}$ is a $\sigma$ algebra

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, measurable-functions, product-measure

This is a problem I have seen while self studying measure theory:

Let $(X,\mathcal{S})$ be a measure space, and $E\in \mathcal{S} \otimes \mathcal{S}$, with $f(x) = (x,x)$ then $K=\{E|f^{-1}(E)\in \mathcal{S} \}$ is a $\sigma$ algebra.

How do I prove $K$ to a $\sigma$ algebra? I am unsure how it contains $\varnothing$, is closed under complement and countable unions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that $\emptyset \in \mathcal{S}\otimes \mathcal{S}$ and $\emptyset \in \mathcal{S}$. Also, we have the following [union](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1026674/preimage-of-the-complement) and [complement](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1026674/preimage-of-the-complement) rules for pre-images:
$$f^{-1}(E^{c}) = (f^{-1}(E))^{c} \quad \mbox{and} \quad f^{-1}\bigg{(}\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}E_{n}\bigg{)} = \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}f^{-1}(E_{n})$$

Comment: This makes a lot of sense! To clarify, $K$ is a sigma algebra on the set $X \times X$?

Comment: No, it is a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $X\times X$ since its elements are also elements of $\mathcal{S}\otimes\mathcal{S}$.

Comment: That is what I meant to type, my apologies!

Comment: No problem! Then you are right!

Comment: @IamWill Since $K$ is a $\sigma$ algebra, why then is $\{x\in X |(x,x)\in E \} \in \mathcal{S}$?